# How do you horizontally position a TextView at a certain percent of the width from one side?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to set my TextView's center to be positioned at 25% of the width from the left side of its parent layout.

Here is what it looks like now:

(A)

```
------------------------------------------
|             Text                       | 
------------------------------------------
          ^          ^          ^         
         25%        50%        75%
```

Here is what I'd like it to look like:

(B)

```
------------------------------------------
|        Text                            |
------------------------------------------
          ^          ^          ^         
         25%        50%        75%
```

Here is the code I have now that is producing (A):

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textView"      
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="text" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like now:

[image: actionbar with textview]

Updated screenshot:

[image]

Comment: your xml is exactly what you wanted.. or post an image for expected result and current

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I just added a screenshot of what it looks like now.  I would like it to be more to the left, where the date TextView's center is 25% from the left.  It's more like 33% from the left now for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `gravity` and `layout_gravity`of your outer `LinearLayout` and in the inner `LinearLayout` you need to set the `gravity` to `right` with `layout_weight` of `0.25` for 25%

**sample:**

EDIT:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.12" >
</View>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The TextView's center still isn't sitting at 25% from the left, which is more apparent when the month string is longer.  I'll post an updated screenshot in a second.

Comment: @JDJ changed above code. If you dont like the position of the textview just change the layout_weight of the View to your needs

Answer (score 1):

try my code buddy, i think thats what u want

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
     >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's close, but the center of the TextView is a little too much to the left.  But your code should work.  I think the overflow icon in the action bar has something to do with it...